# Vue.js: How to specify props in single file component?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-component

I'm defining a [single file component](http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Single-File-Components)

I want to use [props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) option on that component.

But where can I add the code?

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      // note: changing this line won't causes changes
      // with hot-reload because the reloaded component
      // preserves its current state and we are modifying
      // its initial state.
      msg: 'Hello World!'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Look at @Gijsberts answer below it contains an important note about VueJS style guidelines and how to type your props

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After a long time of experiment, I found out a practical solution:

**The project file structure:**

```
src/
  assets/
  components/
    Home.vue
  App.vue
  main.js
package.json
config.js
index.html
```

Now, we want to access the root component -- `App`'s vm fields inside the sub-component `Home.vue`, with `vue-route` on.

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter();

router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'home',
        component: require('./components/Home')
    }
});

router.start(App, 'body');
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>

    <p>The current path: {{ $route.path }}.</p>
    <p>Outer-Value: {{ outer_var }}</p>
    <hr/>

    <!-- The below line is very very important -->
    <router-view :outer_var.sync="outer_var"></router-view>

</template>

<script>
    import Home from './compnents/Home.vue'

    export default {
        replace: false,
        components: { Home },
        data: function() {
            return {
                outer_var: 'Outer Var Init Value.'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p><input v-model="outer_var" /></p>
        <p>Inner-Value: {{ outer_var }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        // relating to the attribute define in outer <router-view> tag.
        props: ['outer_var'],
        data: function () {
            return {
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

## Conclusion

Note that the inner prop bound the property on the attribute of the component tag (`<router-view>` Tag in this case.), **NOT** directly on the parent component.

So, we **must** manually bind the passing props field as an attribute on the component tag. See: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Also, notice I used a `.sync` on that attribute, because the binding is **one-way-down** by default: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types

You can see, sharing the status through nesting components is a bit confused. To make a better practice, we can use [Vuex](http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/en/index.html).

Comment: Prefer the `vue.js` tag instead of the `vuejs` tag, because the first one is getting close to 1k questions, and the last one doesn't even have 10 questions, in fact it should be burninated. You'll get a lot more attention with this ;)

Comment: @YerkoPalma, haha you notice that point... In fact I want to get 5 points on this tag, and then create a synonyms... Everything is aimed at the shiny shiny badge.. Would you mind to give me one point for the goal?

Answer (score 24):

You can do it like this:

*app.js*

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ parentMsg }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ childMsg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['parentMessage'],
  data () {
    return {
      childMessage: 'Child message'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Parent message'
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(App, { props: { parentMessage: this.message } })
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks like `typescript` syntax for me, am I right? How'd look in plain JS? For example with `require`.

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT It's plain JS to me, but in Vue framework. es2015 probably via Babel.

Answer (score 18):

Since a couple of months ago, Vue has its own [styleguide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide) for references and stuff like this. Props are one of the references, actually an essential one.

BAD

```
props: ['status']
```

Good

```
props: {
  status: String
}
```

Even better

```
props: {
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validator: function (value) {
      return [
        'syncing',
        'synced',
        'version-conflict',
        'error'
      ].indexOf(value) !== -1
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more on this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential)

Comment: and you can even use `includes` instead of `indexOf(value) !== -1`

Comment: the styleguide is for v2, he asked for single file components which are (I think) v3

Comment: @cauchi you're not correct, SFC was already a thing in Vue.js 2+ :)

Answer (score 0):

just like this,pass the props while call createApp()

[view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAmlj.png)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).